# Method "collection.find()" accepts at most two arguments

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

```js
const roomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    roomname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    users: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
    },
    createdDate: {
       type: Date,
       default: new Date()
    },
    admins: {
        type: Array
    },
    groupType: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    requests: {
        type:Array
    },
    ip: {
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    country:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
});
const roomModel=mongoose.model('room',roomSchema)
const getUsersInaRoom=async ()=>{
    const res = await roomModel.find({ 'roomname': 'room1' });
    console.log(res);
}
getUsersInaRoom();
```

The error it throws is:

> node:6123) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoInvalidArgumentError: Method "collection.find()" accepts at most two arguments
> at Collection.find (/Users/macpro/Desktop/React/chat-using-socket/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:238:19)

It used to work perfectly a few minutes ago, now throws the above error.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an issue with the new version of mongoose. Run `npm rm mongoose` to uninstall the current version, `npm i mongoose@5.13.8` to install the previous one and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are specifying some of the following options when connecting to MongoDB: `useNewUrlParser`, `useUnifiedTopology`, `useFindAndModify`, `useCreateIndex`. If you are, remove these from options object and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find one just use `findOne({})`

```
const getUsersInaRoom = async() => {
    const res = await roomModel.findOne({ 'roomname': 'room1' });
    console.log(res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the key should not be a string.

Example:

```js
// const res = await roomModel.find({ 'roomname': 'room1' });

const res = await roomModel.find({ roomname: 'room1' });
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when you call find() before mongoose.connect() succeeds. Await mongoose.connect() before calling find().